# push registery used in j2me

Tags: java-me

i have developed two  apps in j2me. both uses push registery.but when i use any one app another app is invocked  automaticaly due to same port number used for listening sms....
this is actually my guess ..is it so....have a solution to anybody

Comment: What psuh registry entries do you have in your jad/manifest ?

Comment: If you're using the same port number, have you tried using a different port number for another app?

Comment: Any updates with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same port number for both apps, just try to assign a different port number  for the second application.